# TF_NO_FRAME_ID: Ignoring transform with child_frame_id

Tags: ros, pi-tracker, skeleton-tracker

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I've tried the pi_tracker package. I have no errors running skeleton.launch and tracker.launch. However, when I rosrun rviz, I met the following errors

[ERROR] [1316763642.701371303]: TF_NO_FRAME_ID: Ignoring transform with child_frame_id "/right_shoulder"  from authority "/skeleton_tracker" because frame_id not set
[ERROR] [1316763642.701422097]: TF_NO_FRAME_ID: Ignoring transform with child_frame_id "/right_elbow"  from authority "/skeleton_tracker" because frame_id not set
[ERROR] [1316763642.701475147]: TF_NO_FRAME_ID: Ignoring transform with child_frame_id "/right_hand"  from authority "/skeleton_tracker" because frame_id not set

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11287/tf_no_frame_id:-ignoring-transform-with-child_frame_id/) by [ychua](https://answers.ros.org/users/1060/ychua/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2011-09-22

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ychua](https://answers.ros.org/users/1060/ychua/) on 2011-09-22**:
In rviz, in TF display. I got status: warning "/openni_camera: No transform from [/openni_camera] to frame[/world] /openni_depth_frame: No transform from [/openni_depth_frame to frame[/world]" etc....

**Comment by [ychua](https://answers.ros.org/users/1060/ychua/) on 2011-09-22**:
The robot model in the rviz has no errors. I've also changed the 'skel_to_joint_map' parameter in the tracker_params.yaml, to correspond with the joint names with my robot urdf model.  I also changed the line in the 'self.cmd_joints.position[self.cmd_joints.name.index('myRobot_jointName')] = right_shoulder_lift_angle' in the tracker_joint_controller.py to my robot urdf's joint name.

Is there anywhere else I need to change in the code? Thanks a lot!

**Comment by [ychua](https://answers.ros.org/users/1060/ychua/) on 2011-09-22**:
[ERROR] [1316763642.701371303]: TF_NO_FRAME_ID: Ignoring transform with child_frame_id "/right_shoulder"  from authority "/skeleton_tracker" because frame_id not set
[ERROR] [1316763642.701422097]: TF_NO_FRAME_ID: Ignoring transform with child_frame_id "/right_elbow"  from authority "/skeleton_tracker" because frame_id not set
[ERROR] [1316763642.701475147]: TF_NO_FRAME_ID: Ignoring transform with child_frame_id "/right_hand"  from authority "/skeleton_tracker" because frame_id not set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to change the fixed frame and target frame to something connected in rviz.  See the [user guide](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rviz/UserGuide#Frames)

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-11-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

check your urdf:
my case was

```
<joint
    name="right_forward_steering_joint"
    type="continuous">
    <origin
      xyz="-0.71499 0.65792 0.2505"
      rpy="1.5708 0 0" />
    <parent
      link="base_link" />
    <child
      link="right_forward_steering" />
    <axis
      xyz="0 0 0" />
</joint>
```

the xyz axis was (0 0 0), i solved it by adding 1 in the axis of rotation
so it will be

```
<axis xyz="0 1 0" />
```

---

Originally posted by [youssef desouky](https://answers.ros.org/users/35943/youssef-desouky/) with karma: 11 on 2020-07-14

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1